# S2n library doesn't link with arm

Tags: libraries

When I am trying to compile amazon's s2n(opnen source TLS implementation) library on arm64, It gives me the error

```
hidden symbol 'pthread_atfork' in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread_nonshared.a (pthread_atfokr.OS) is referenced by DSO.
fatal link failed.
```

The library works well with linux-x86.

Answer (score 0):

Extracting pthread_atfork.o form libpthread.a and including the file pthrea_atfork.o in makefile made s2n work on ARM.